# Spring Boot Web Security Application, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated, what can I use instead to make my WebSecurityConfig class work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security

I am very new to spring boot, and I am following along in a tutorial about the spring boot web security, and the tutorial is supposed to be demonstrating how to set up and configure the WebSecurityConfig class that they have us create.  The problem that I am running into is twofold.

First, they have me extending my WebSecurityConfig class with the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, which is deprecated and I can not seem to find anything related to how to update this anywhere.  I tried to use the WsCongfigurerAdapater insdead but that doesn't seem to do much better.

Second is the configure method at the bottom of the file, it seems as though all of the http methods such ass .authorizeHttpRequest(), .authorizeRequest(), .antMatchers(), .requestMatchers() are all either deprecated or incorrect.

How can I update my WebSecurityConfig class to fix these few problems?  I have included the code within the WebSecurityConfig.java class file, as well as the images of the messages I get.

Finally what happened when I used the WsConfigurerAdapter or if I leave the file as they tell me to set it up is that I can not navigate to any route other than the /login route.  Every other route that I try redirects me back to this.

Please Help.

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
package com.securewebapp;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;

import com.securewebapp.auth.MySQLUserDetailsService;

import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMethod;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private MySQLUserDetailsService mySQLUserDetailsService;
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
         .userDetailsService(mySQLUserDetailsService)
         .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod, "/", "/home", "/register", "/css/**.css", "/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
    }
}
[WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter][1]
[![authorizeHttpRequest][2]][2]
[![HttpMethod][3]][3]
[![antMathers][4]][4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your existing SecurityConfig to create Beans instead of extending the adapter.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MySQLUserDetailsService mySQLUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(mySQLUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/", "/home", "/register", "/css/**.css", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(config -> config.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

You can read this blog post on Spring.io to get better understanding.
https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

You might run into issues with the AuthenticationManagerBuilder and people have asked the same question in the comments of the blog, maybe you can go through that as well.

Comment: I tried this and did read through the blog, it really didn't help a whole lot, but thanks for the tips and the idea.  I am clearly not advanced enough to start working with security for spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

i am use Springboot3.1.4

```
 @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @EnableMethodSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig  {
    
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new MySQLUserDetailsService();
        }
    
         static class MySQLUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                return User.builder().username("admin").password("123456").authorities("admin").build();
            }
        }
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            return http.authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c.requestMatchers("/", "/home", "/register", "/css/**.css", "/js/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .formLogin(c -> c.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
                    .logout(LogoutConfigurer::permitAll)
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, I appreciate the tip.  This did not work for me because I did not have some of the other dependencies this code is depending on.  It just confused me even more.